# Java finite stream termination

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to make a streaming version of `StringTokenizer` but I am having some problems terminating the stream correctly.

```
public Stream<String> tokenize(String text) {
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(text);
    return Stream.generate(tokenizer::nextToken)
        .takeWhile(s -> tokenizer.hasMoreTokens());
}
```

But when I run this code, the last token is missing:

```
Stream<String> tokens = new DefaultTokenizer().tokenize("   a b   c d\te  f\n");
tokens.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Results in:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

I have tried using `Stream.iterate` like this: `Stream.iterate(tokenizer.nextToken(), s -> tokenizer.hasMoreTokens(), s -> tokenizer.nextToken())` but the result is the same.

I am obviously terminating the stream as soon as the predicate `hasMoreTokens` passes, but I need to take the last element after that, how can I terminate after taking the last element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like in all the other answers I would avoid using `StringTokenizer`.

To avoid processing the whole string you can use `Pattern.splitAsStream(String)` instead of the usual `split` method.

So in your case something like this should have similar results as using `StringTokenizer`. (The string is `split at any (non-empty) sequence of white-space`)

```
Pattern.compile("\\s+").splitAsStream(text)
```

Comment: Yes you are right. To be honest I just copied the String that is used in `StringTokenizer` as delimiter thinking it should just work and didn't test it. Your `"\\s+"` is much cleaner.

Comment: It’s a bit confusing with `StringTokenizer` that `" \t\n\r\f"` means split at any one of those characters.

Comment: It works almost the same. This solution also returns "" (empty string) as 1st element in comparison to other (StringTokenizer based) solutions using the string in my post. But this is what I was looking for, much cleaner, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class, you may want to think otherwise. **Edit:** I deleted my solution from this answer since the one in [the answer by magicmn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66195078/5772882) is much better.

**Edit: What went wrong in your code?** You tried:

```
Stream.iterate(tokenizer.nextToken(), s -> tokenizer.hasMoreTokens(), s -> tokenizer.nextToken())
```

What happens here is that the stream uses `s -> tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()` to determine whether to include the present token, `s`, in the stream. At the point it does that for the final token, `f`, it obviously has already drawn it from the `StringTokenizer`, so the `StringTokenizer` returns `false` for `hasMoreTokens()`, and `f` is not included in the stream.

Comment: I am open to suggestions about removing `StringTokenizer`, but I would prefer to keep the stream "optimal", and using `String.split` would pre-tokenize if that makes sense? I would split tokens in advance which the user might not need. I don't know of a simpler solution than this class.

Comment: I had the same thought, which was why I didn’t dive into `String.split()` straight away. I think you want [the answer my magicmn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66195078/5772882). It’s a lot eleganter than mine, avoids `StringTokenizer` and seems space and time efficient also when you end up using just the first few tokens from the stream.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation in the edit, appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

A small adjustment your supplier to return null at the end and takeWhile(nonNull) will allow you to continue with Tokeniser:

```
public Stream<String> tokenize(String text) {
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(text);
    return Stream.generate(() -> tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() ? tokenizer.nextToken() : null)
                           .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you try this?

```java
return Stream.generate(tokenizer::nextToken).limit((long) tokenizer.countTokens());
```

limit the stream by total token

Answer (score 1):

StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is not recommended to use anymore. Here is an example of using `split()` instead

```
public Stream<String> tokenize(String text) {
    String[] split = text.split("\\s");
    return Arrays.stream(split).map(String::trim).filter( s -> (!s.isEmpty()));
}
```

or even more compact

```
public Stream<String> tokenize(String text) {
    return Arrays.stream(text.split("\\s"))
        .map(String::trim)
        .filter( s -> (!s.isEmpty()));
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this run through the text "in advance"? I was trying to avoid this and deliberately used a legacy class to get a more streaming solution where I could stream data and let consumers decide when they want to stop, for an example, `.limit(5)`. Using this solution, I would parse tokens which the user wouldn't even use.

Comment: Maybe so but using a legacy class that is not recommended can't be a better solution.